# How can I program the last digits of Fibonacci numbers?

Tags: integer-sequence, modular-arithmetic, digits

Is there a way to compute the last digits of an arbitrarily large Fibonacci number?

For the $10^n$th Fibonacci number, we can just find the $2^n$-th Fibonacci number (if that isn't too large) $\bmod n$, and then use the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem), since we know it is a multiple of $5^n$ (the [Pisano period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisano_period) is $4\cdot5^n$ which divides $10^n$) to find the last $n$ digits.

However, is there a way to find the last digits of the $n$-th Fibonacci number efficiently if $n$ is not a power of $10$?

A way to program this would probably require a way to reference the last two intermediate values and add them together, and then taking the result $\bmod 10^d$. Taking the value $\bmod 3\times10^d$ would be preferred because this allows the calculation to be iterated.

Answer (score 17):

This can be computed almost instantaneously due to one curious property of the Fibonacci numbers: Their sequence is periodic modulo any modulus $m$. These periods are known as [Pisano periods](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PisanoPeriod.html) $\pi(m)$. For 10 the period is 60. Therefore we have

```
FibLastDigit[n_] := Mod[Fibonacci[Mod[n, 60]], 10]
```

This is presumably faster than any other method. Even faster would be to precompute the sequence from 1 to 60. In this case the problem is to merely compute `Mod[n,60]`.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a *curious* property — the sequence is described by a recurrence relation on the previous two terms, and there are only a finite number of pairs of residues mod any given base, so you can't avoid repeating a pair eventually :)

Comment: @hobbs:  Right, the period can't be any greater than $m^2$ by that argument ($m^2 - 1$, really, since the residue pair $(0,0)$ always maps to itself in any base.)

Comment: Thanks for the link to Pisano periods above!  I "discovered" this property of Fibonacci numbers during a boring meeting once, and it's nice to know that it's already been named & explored.

Comment: Since this became popular, here are some notes: 1. Pisano periods were discussed earlier [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18481/). 2 The current solution as implemented only does the last digit, and is **less general** than the other answers.3. If you look at [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A096363), to extend the Pisano period approach to the general "last $n$ digits" problem, you will find that e.g. for $n=8$, you need to $\bmod 150,000,000$ your original number before feeding to `Fibonacci[]`, which of course you can skip if the original input is less than that. ;)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert why is it nice to know that?  Because you wouldn't want to have to deal with the fame and fortune of being the first to discover it?

Answer (score 11):

Using an *undocumented* function (see [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/123241) as well) to implement the matrix form of the Fibonacci recurrence (see [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/31634) as well):

```
With[{n = 1003, m = 8}, 
     Algebra`MatrixPowerMod[{{1, 1}, {1, 0}}, n - 1, 10^m][[1, 1]]]
   96035877

Mod[Fibonacci[1003], 1*^8]
   96035877
```

Answer (score 8):

I combined MatrixPowerMod from Bressoud & Wagon's book, A Course in Computational Number Theory, with a `Fold` formulation from @J.M.'s, to give `FibonacciMod` as follows. This code is what is essentially contained in the undocumented Algebra`MatrixPowerMod function found by @J.M.'s (+1).

```
FibonacciMod[0, m_] = 0;

FibonacciMod[n_, m_] :=
   Fold[
      If[#2 == 1, Mod[#1.#1.{{0, 1}, {1, 1}}, m], Mod[#1.#1, m]] &, {{0, 1}, {1, 1}},
      Rest[IntegerDigits[n, 2]]][[1, 2]]
```

`FibonacciMod[n,m]` is slower than `Mod[Fibonacci[n],m]` for small n, but much faster for large n. To echo J.M.'s example,

```
FibonacciMod[1003],10^8]
```

> 96035877

Also,

```
AbsoluteTiming[FibonacciMod[10^20-1, 10^10]]
```

> {0.00323, 2900390626}